# List C# perdendo o que já foi adicionado

Tags: c#, json, mvc, asp, lista

Sou iniciante e estou desenvolvendo um carrinho de compras. A rotina que pensei foi: A cada clique no botão adicionar, o produto é enviado para a controller via requisição ajax. Lá eu já tenho um list criado. Sendo assim, adiciono o produto no list e salvo o list numa session. Retorno a session pra view e populo meu carrinho de compras. Porém isto me gerou um problema, a cada clique, o método é chamado e consequentemente o list é instanciado novamente, isso dá um clear no meu list e perco os produtos adicionados anteriormente. O objetivo disso é permitir que o usuário navegue entre as páginas sem perder o que for adicionando no carrinho.

```
public JsonResult AddCart(int _cod, string _foto, string _nome, string _categoria, decimal _desconto, decimal _preco)
    {
        List<Produtos> listCart = new List<Produtos>();

        Produtos item = new Produtos();
            item.cod = _cod;
            item.foto = _foto;
            item.nome = _nome;
            item.categoria = _categoria;
            item.desconto = _desconto;
            item.preco = _preco;

            listCart.Add(item);

        Session["SessionList"] = listCart;
        var list = Session["SessionList"] as List<Produtos>;


        var v = Json(new { listCart }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque você não está atribuindo para a lista o que já está salvo.

No começo do seu método adicione o seguinte código

```
List<Produtos> listCart;
if(Session["SessionList"] == null)
     listCart = new List<Produtos>();
else
    listCart = Session["SessionList"] as List<Produtos>;
```

Ele vai verificar se a `Session` já existe, caso sim, ele preenche a lista e será feito um `append`, caso a `Session` não exista, cria-se uma nova lista.

Comment: estava postando praticamente a mesma resposta

Comment: @LeandroAngelo essa semana estava ajudando um amigo justamente nisso, ai quando bati o olho...

Comment: Muito bom! Funcionou, obrigado! Só pra aproveitar o post, esta é a melhor forma de se fazer? Estava lendo um artigo que fala que session consome muito recurso do servidor...

Comment: Não é só a questão de consumir recursos, mas o ideal é manter a sua solução o máximo stateless que conseguir. Por exemplo se você tiver uma camada de Web.API as duas aplicações não vão compartilhar a mesma sessão.